# How to serialize an object inside of a dll?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

So, I've a project that loads dlls on runtime and I'm using reflection and an interface to create the dlls.

I created a user control referenced as dll (at runtime) that has a List that needs to be serialized. It serializes the project right, but when I try to load it I can't deserialize it.

now, I tested this usercontrol on another project that references the user control as project and it worked well.

Here's my code:

```
    static public object SerializeLoad(string sFilename)
    {
        try
        {
            object _object = null;
            Stream stream = File.Open(sFilename, FileMode.Open);
            //BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            XmlSerializer bformatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ElementTodo), "ToDo");

            //_object = (_object.GetType())bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
            _object = bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            return _object;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I tried both, binary and xml and both through "There is an error in XML document (2, 2)." Any ideas why is this?

---

The generated XML is as follows:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <ArrayOfElementTodo xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; xmlns="ToDo"> 
      <ElementTodo Title="a" content="aa" isDone="false" /> 
      <ElementTodo Title="b" content="bb" isDone="false" /> 
      <ElementTodo Title="c" content="cc" isDone="false" /> 
      <ElementTodo Title="d" content="dd" isDone="false" /> 
  </ArrayOfElementTodo>
```

Comment: If you serialized it to an XML file, then could you post the contents of this file?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfElementTodo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="ToDo">
  <ElementTodo Title="a" content="aa" isDone="false" />
  <ElementTodo Title="b" content="bb" isDone="false" />
  <ElementTodo Title="c" content="cc" isDone="false" />
  <ElementTodo Title="d" content="dd" isDone="false" />
</ArrayOfElementTodo>

Comment: The serialized data is an *array*, you are trying to deserialize just one element.

Comment: Even if I do an array, throughs the exception...

Comment: Just curious - have you tried this with binary serialization? That may not meet your needs long term but it might rule out a few XML serialization possibilities...

Comment: Yeah, I've tried both, I think this has something to do with reflection but I don't know what...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in order to be able to deserialize an object, the type of the object must be available since .NET is a statically typed environment. (Every instance which lives in your program must have a type with a list of its members etc.)

Or, you could use C# 4 dynamic to deserialize arbitrary XML ([1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/02/04/dynamic-xml-reader-with-c-and-net-4-0.aspx), [2](http://nomadic-developer.com/2010/04/05/using-dynamic-with-c-to-read-xml/)).

Comment: Is there anyway I can add this type to the appdomain so it's not isolated and I can deserialize it?

Comment: Is it a problem to just reference the project, as you did?